# Open source command line subtitle converter

Tags: linux, command-line, conversion, subtitles

Are there any open source, command line, **subtitle converters** - preferably for Linux?

Answer (score 65):

You can try [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) (great tool !) :

```
$ ffmpeg -i file.srt file.vtt
```

Comment: That tool can convert anything :)

Comment: @IvanP Apparently not ttml to $x$, though :(

Comment: keeps surprising me every time!

Comment: Open source, command line and supports many more formats than FFmpeg - https://github.com/mantas-done/subtitles

Comment: Not that STYLE in vtt format is not supported. Doing the reverse conversion [leads to an empty file](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9064).

Answer (score 19):

very simple and effective oneliner i use to convert subtitles:

```
for i in *.ass ; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "$i.srt" ; done
```

just change `ass` and `srt` according to your needs.

Comment: `for i in *.ass ; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.srt" ; done`

Answer (score 8):

[Subtitles perl swiss army knife](http://karasik.eu.org/software/) (scroll to the end of the page).

[Here](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/125978) you can find more options.

Also, [mplayer/mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) has some dumpXXXsub options, which might work. I never tried this, but reading the man, it should work. Example:

```
-dumpmpsub (MPlayer only)
              Convert the given subtitle (specified with the -sub option) to MPlayer's subtitle format, MPsub.  Creates a dump.mpsub file in the current directory.
```

Comment: Indeed this is handy, sadly though only three different formats are supported; .srt, .sub, .smi.

Comment: I checked the Mplayer and Mencoder out. Didnt get it working though. And it supports only SRT, SMI, SUB and JACO. A good suggestion though, thanks.

Comment: Works nice, thanks! Here: http://pastebin.com/T6DM9xbq is my converter based on this with framerate detection using mplayer

Answer (score 6):

The open source program [Subtitle Edit](http://www.nikse.dk/SubtitleEdit/Help#commandline) has a command line converter and is available for both Windows and Linux.

> **Syntax**: `SubtitleEdit /convert "pattern" "name-of-format-without-spaces"`
>
> **Example 1**: `SubtitleEdit /convert sub1.srt sami`
>   **Result**: Will convert sub1.srt to sub1.sub to SAMI format
>
> **Example 2**: `SubtitleEdit /convert *.srt adobeencore`
>   **Result**: Will convert all .srt files to Adobe Encore format

For **Linux** the command line needs to be slightly longer…

> **Syntax**: `mono SubtitleEdit.exe /convert "pattern" "name-of-format-without-spaces"`

…but could easily be wrapped in a script.

Comment: The GUI works, but I got an error when running from the command line.. .I needed to install `libmono-winforms` for the GUI to work (as stated in the README)... Maybe there is something *extra* which is needed for the CLI to work... I get an `AttachConsole...` error.  using Ubuntu 10.04 ...

Comment: This seems to be fixed in version 3.2.3 - at least on Ubuntu

Comment: *@Johanz:* Thanks. Version 3.2.3 works. It converted a `.ass` to SubRip (.srt) ... Just one thing I notieced: it produces `\r\n` (CRLF) line endings, even when the source line-ending is `\n` ... but that would rarely be a problem and is easily fixed with `sed` if need be.

Comment: +1 as this is a really good converter and an open source application. And it has a cmd line interface.

Answer (score 3):

I found that some players (e.g., Google Drive video player) do not like the .srt generated from:

```
ffmpeg -i subtitles.ass <blah>.srt
```

or:

```
SubtitleEdit /convert subtitles.ass subrip
```

but:

```
ffmpeg -i subtitles.ass -codec:s text subtitles.srt
```

...did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

What is it you want to convert exactly? If it is between subtitle formats then it depends on which formats you are talking about. Those which are bitmap based will require OCR to convert to text format and generally always require user input for confirming the accuracy of the OCR

If it is all text formats then [Jubler](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/Jubler) or [Aegisub](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/Aegisub) may be of use

Comment: Simple text subtitles. SRT, STL, SUB, PAC. Back and forth.

Comment: @johnas - my answer updated with a couple of possibilities

Comment: Thanks Shevek, but none of the above was command line operational. Though they would've been perfect if I could use the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

rename the file name using sed

```
for i in ./*.ass ; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "$( echo "$i"|sed 's/\.ass//g' ).srt" ; done
```

if you want to delete the `.srt` file after converting, just add a rm command afterwards.

```
for i in ./*.ass ; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "$( echo "$i"|sed 's/\.ass//g' ).srt"  &&  rm -f "$i"  ; done
```

Comment: What if the file name is `big.assassins.assured` (plus the extension)? Your `sed` will name it `bigassinsured`. Without `sed` and without this flaw: `"${i%.ass}.srt"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

file="*.srt"                     # Find file
ffmpeg -i "$file" "${file%.*}.vtt"   # Convert file  
rm "$file"                         # Remove file .srt from your dir
```

## if you want to convert more file using this program in for loop.

Comment: What if Ffmpeg aborts?

Comment: ffmpeg is open source  multimedia library.

Answer (score 0):

With Windows batch file, you could use this to convert all text-subtitle files in folder to SRT

```
for %%i in (*.vtt .ass .ssa) do ffmpeg -i "%%i" "%%~ni.srt"
```

Answer (score 0):

For converting the whole directory and also changing the extension of every file.
You can use `find` command and combined it with `${%.*}` to remove the `.srt` and use the new extension `.vtt` with this one-line command.

```
find . -name "*.srt" -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i {} "${0%.*}$1" ' {} ".vtt" \;
```

The reason to call bash is to use the `${0%.*}` to find basename.

- If you want to read more about *[Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)*

The `{}` after `ffmpeg -i {} "${0%.*}$1"` is the argument `$0` that send into the ffmpeg command.

The `".vtt"` is the argument $1.

So `${0%.*}$1` became ***basename.vtt***